# What is the relationship between xinetd and mysql?

Tags: mysql, xinetd

My mariadb was can not start up, and there are the part of the logs:

```
Aug 16 15:52:19 ha-node1 xinetd[1523]: EXIT: mysqlchk signal=13 pid=12120 duration=0(sec)
Aug 16 15:52:21 ha-node1 xinetd[1523]: START: mysqlchk pid=12124 from=::ffff:192.168.8.101
Aug 16 15:52:21 ha-node1 xinetd[1523]: EXIT: mysqlchk signal=13 pid=12124 duration=0(sec)
Aug 16 15:52:23 ha-node1 xinetd[1523]: START: mysqlchk pid=12130 from=::ffff:192.168.8.101
Aug 16 15:52:23 ha-node1 xinetd[1523]: EXIT: mysqlchk signal=13 pid=12130 duration=0(sec)
Aug 16 15:52:25 ha-node1 xinetd[1523]: START: mysqlchk pid=12134 from=::ffff:192.168.8.101
Aug 16 15:52:25 ha-node1 xinetd[1523]: EXIT: mysqlchk status=1 pid=12134 duration=0(sec)
Aug 16 15:52:27 ha-node1 xinetd[1523]: START: mysqlchk pid=12139 from=::ffff:192.168.8.101
Aug 16 15:52:27 ha-node1 xinetd[1523]: EXIT: mysqlchk signal=13 pid=12139 duration=0(sec)
Aug 16 15:52:29 ha-node1 xinetd[1523]: START: mysqlchk pid=12143 from=::ffff:192.168.8.101
Aug 16 15:52:29 ha-node1 xinetd[1523]: EXIT: mysqlchk signal=13 pid=12143 duration=0(sec)
Aug 16 15:52:31 ha-node1 xinetd[1523]: START: mysqlchk pid=12147 from=::ffff:192.168.8.101
Aug 16 15:52:31 ha-node1 xinetd[1523]: EXIT: mysqlchk status=1 pid=12147 duration=0(sec)
Aug 16 15:52:33 ha-node1 xinetd[1523]: START: mysqlchk pid=12154 from=::ffff:192.168.8.101
Aug 16 15:52:33 ha-node1 xinetd[1523]: EXIT: mysqlchk signal=13 pid=12154 duration=0(sec)
Aug 16 15:52:35 ha-node1 xinetd[1523]: START: mysqlchk pid=12244 from=::ffff:192.168.8.101
Aug 16 15:52:35 ha-node1 xinetd[1523]: EXIT: mysqlchk signal=13 pid=12244 duration=0(sec)
Aug 16 15:52:37 ha-node1 xinetd[1523]: START: mysqlchk pid=12248 from=::ffff:192.168.8.101
Aug 16 15:52:37 ha-node1 xinetd[1523]: EXIT: mysqlchk status=1 pid=12248 duration=0(sec)
Aug 16 15:52:39 ha-node1 xinetd[1523]: START: mysqlchk pid=12253 from=::ffff:192.168.8.101
Aug 16 15:52:39 ha-node1 xinetd[1523]: EXIT: mysqlchk status=1 pid=12253 duration=0(sec)
Aug 16 15:52:41 ha-node1 xinetd[1523]: START: mysqlchk pid=12258 from=::ffff:192.168.8.101
Aug 16 15:52:41 ha-node1 xinetd[1523]: EXIT: mysqlchk signal=13 pid=12258 duration=0(sec)
Aug 16 15:52:43 ha-node1 xinetd[1523]: START: mysqlchk pid=12264 from=::ffff:192.168.8.101
Aug 16 15:52:43 ha-node1 xinetd[1523]: EXIT: mysqlchk signal=13 pid=12264 duration=0(sec)
Aug 16 15:52:45 ha-node1 xinetd[1523]: START: mysqlchk pid=12268 from=::ffff:192.168.8.101
Aug 16 15:52:45 ha-node1 xinetd[1523]: EXIT: mysqlchk signal=13 pid=12268 duration=0(sec)
```

So, I just want to know what's the relationship between the `xinetd` and the `mysql`

Comment: These logs aren't relevant to why MariaDB isn't starting.  [`mysqlchk`](https://gist.github.com/aw/1071141) is an xinetd service configuration for checking the status of MySQL using an HTTP request.  Since your host is `ha-node1`, with "ha" meaning (presumably) "high availability" as in HAProxy, it would make sense if you have something like that set up... but it's only monitoring your database.  Is that what you are trying to figure out?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Oh, yeah. i have 3 nodes to do the `mariadb cluster`, the cluster success, works perfect, and now I just want to start one, and the other two down, but I did not success start up only one mysql.